# How to execute SQL query stored in a table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I have a table having one of the columns that stores SQL query.

```sql
create table test1
(
    name varchar(20),
    stmt varchar(500)
);

insert into test1 (name, stmt) 
values ('first', 'select id from data where id = 1;')
```

Data table is like:

```sql
create table data
(
    id number,
    subject varchar(500)
);

insert into data (id, subject) values (1, 'test subject1');
insert into data (id, subject) values (2, 'test subject2');
insert into data (id, subject) values (3, 'test subject2');
```

Now every time on insert in `test1`, I need to execute the query that gets inserted in `stmt` column of `test1` and insert queried data to result table:

```sql
create table result
(
    id number,
    subject varchar(500)
);
```

For that I am writing a trigger that gets executed on every insert in `test1` like as follows:

```sql
create or replace TRIGGER  "TEST_AFTER_INSERT" 
BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE ON test1
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
sql_stmt VARCHAR2(500);
BEGIN
select stmt into sql_stmt from data where name = :NEW.name;
insert into result(id, subject)
select id,subject from data where id in ('stmt');
END;
```

Could you please let me know how to achieve this, above trigger is throwing error that I am not able to understand.

Comment: It sounds like you need "Dynamic SQL": https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg09dyn.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dynamic query in your trigger as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TEST_AFTER_INSERT" AFTER  -- CHANGED IT TO AFTER AS NAME SUGGESTS
    INSERT OR UPDATE ON TEST1
    FOR EACH ROW -- REMOVED DECLARE SECTION
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'INSERT INTO result
    SELECT ID, SUBJECT FROM DATA WHERE ID IN ('
                      || RTRIM(:NEW.STMT, ';')
                      || ')';
     -- SINGLE QUERY TO INSERT THE DATA
     -- USED RTRIM AS STMT HAS ; AT THE END
END;
```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks @Tajash.

Could you please also suggest me a query for above trigger for selecting records based on stored sql query.

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT ID, SUBJECT FROM DATA WHERE ID IN (' || RTRIM(stmt where name ='first' ';') || ')';

Basically in trigger we can directly get the query to execute by using directly :NEW.STMT but in simple query I want to get the STMT based on the value of name column. 
So my problem is using where clause to get the stmt in a normal query(without trigger)

Comment: Ohh. Seems like it is complicated now. I suggest you to create a new question for it so that it do not create mess here.

Comment: posted at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57851152/execute-sql-query-stored-in-a-table

Comment: @Tajash pls have a look at detailed query at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57851152/execute-sql-query-stored-in-a-table

Answer (score 0):

Consider direct insertion :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TEST_AFTER_INSERT"
  BEFORE INSERT or UPDATE ON test1
  FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
BEGIN
  insert into result(id, subject)
  select id, subject from data where name = :NEW.name;
END;
```